# Interpretation of the ending of Lost In Translation

Tags: plot-explanation, analysis, lost-in-translation

Bob Harris gets ready to leave Japan and initially bids goodbye to Charlotte near  the elevator in the hotel.  He sees her again on the way and they share a kiss and he whispers something in her ear to which Charlotte acknowledges. I cannot wrap my head around the significance of that scene, what does it mean?

Anyone explanation would be greatly helpful.

Comment: I think you're right about the decision on not including subtitles. The characters' feelings of alienation is a central theme.

Comment: You had two completely seperate questions in this question.  I've edited out the second one.  Please post it as a seperate question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Roger Ebert made the following two comments.  This is from his [original review](http://www.rogerebert.com/reviews/lost-in-translation-2003):

> I loved the moment near the end when Bob runs after Charlotte and says something in her ear, and we're not allowed to hear it.
>   We shouldn't be allowed to hear it. It's between them, and by this point in the movie, they've become real enough to deserve their privacy.

This is from his [second review](http://www.rogerebert.com/reviews/great-movie-lost-in-translation-2003), when he included *Lost in Translation* in his list of "great movies":

> We get all we need in simply knowing they share a moment private to them, and *seeing* that it contains something true before they part forever.

So the significance is that they get some closure, even if we don't know exactly how.